# Eclipse "Waiting for virtual machine to exit"

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, ant

I'm working on a blackberry project using eclipse and bb-ant tools.  I've created a build.xml file to perform the build.  Everytime I try to run an Ant build, eclipse pops up the progress dialog and it hangs stating "Waiting for virtual machine to exit."

I downloaded an open source Blackberry project that has an ant build and it is showing the same behavior.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Edit:

I used the command line to build my xml file and it built fine.  However, when I tried from Eclipse it still hangs.

I've tried both the standard eclipse plugin directory and the path I downloaded ant to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check if [your `ANT_HOME` settings are correct](http://mrmx.blogspot.com/2008/08/strange-anteclipse-ganymede-error.html) (see also this [blog post](http://csm2kh.blogspot.com/2008/01/error-waiting-for-virtual-machine-to.html)).

`"Window > Preference > Ant > Runtime"`: "`Ant Home Entries`".
if the jars files are from a plugin directory (beside the default '`org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20090120-1145`' one) and not an independent ant installation, that might explain the problem.
Try clicking the "`Ant Home`" button on the right side and setting up ant home such as "`C:\path\to\apache-ant-1.7.0`"

There are similar bugs to this kind of situation ([bug 173419](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=173419), [ticket 91](http://issues.objectstyle.org/jira/browse/WOL-91)).
It is worth [checking the JVM used for the project](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg13248.html).
It can also occurs when a ant task [is poorly implemented](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=rview&goto=212154&th=67603).

Comment: I'll take a look when I get back home.  I'm pretty sure they're to the default plugin directory.  I could try installing Ant standalone and see if that helps.

Comment: It was pointing to the eclipse plugin.  I also downloaded 1.8, put it on the C:\ drive and pointed to it, with the same results.

Comment: @taylonrr: just added a few links, but nothing definitive. It is worth double-checking what actual `ANT_HOME` is considered at runtime (even if the Eclipse has a correct `ANT_HOME`).

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I'll check those out tonight.

Answer (score 2):

You had the problem because the java version ant tries to run with is incorrect.

By default, eclipse will try to run the ant build with the java version it uses to compile the java files (Blackberry JRE), which won't work! You need to change the jre version by choosing "Run As... > Ant build". Before clicking run, go to the JRE tab, choose "Separate JRE:" and change "Blackberry JRE " to a standard java JRE. Press the run button and everything should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this problem also. Although I never used the same solution, you pointed me in the same direction.

I was using a ant file as a builder in my project, and I disabled the Allocate Console build option.  This is when I hit the 'Waiting for virtual machine to exit'.
So I simply enabled the Launch in background option and it worked.